Getting "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" when trying to delete registry key using DeleteKey from winreg Python library
I'm trying to implement a simple interface the create, set , get and delete registry key with winreg in Python.
Here is my code:
import winreg

REG_PATH = r"SOFTWARE\MyApplication"

class RegistryMgr:
    @staticmethod
    def set_reg(name, value):
        '''
        Sets the specified key @ REG_PATH to the specified value.
        If the key does not exist, it is created.
        '''
        with winreg.CreateKeyEx(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE) as registry_key:
            winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)

    @staticmethod
    def get_reg(name):
        '''
        Reads and returns the specified key @ REG_PATH.
        Returns None if the key does not exist.
        '''
        try:
            with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, winreg.KEY_READ) as registry_key:
                value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(registry_key, name)
            return value
        except WindowsError:
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def delete_reg(name):
        '''
        Deletes the specified key @ REG_PATH.
        '''
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as registry_key:
            winreg.DeleteKey(registry_key, name)

When I test with the code below, I a get a "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" at line 3, which doesn't make sense to me since the key exists.
RegistryMgr.set_reg("CONF_PATH", "C:\some_location")
value = RegistryMgr.get_reg("CONF_PATH")
RegistryMgr.delete_reg("CONF_PATH")
value = RegistryMgr.get_reg("CONF_PATH")
RegistryMgr.set_reg("CONF_PATH", "C:\some_other_location")
value = RegistryMgr.get_reg("CONF_PATH")

Can someone tell me what is the issue with my implementation for delete_reg?

The CONF_PATH item that you add to the registry, is a value not a key. You need to change your delete_reg method to call DeleteValue.
